# HP printer connected but "Unable to add document to print job"

Tags: cups

Any ideas anyone?
This is all I have: the printer werrs so the connection is there; I'm in group lpadmin; I've looked in /var/log/cups/error_log and there is no more information.  It used to work but then..

The error message doesn't make sense - why is there a print job without a document?  Yes I have turned it off and on again. Yes it is a pi4 with buster.  I am assuming it is permissions.  I cannot contact HP support because my WIFE LIKES TO BE IN CONTROL OF EVERYTHING and she has a mac.  A case of mental abuse I am sure.  Could it be a Mac compatability thing?  If so can someone tell me how to fix the pi while breaking the mac's printing? That would be good; she might contact support then...

Comment: *"The error message doesn't make sense - why is there a print job without a document?"* -> IMO that's a misreading.  It doesn't say there is an existing print job with no documents.  It says there is a document that cannot be added to a print job, for whatever reason.  It may be that it cannot create a print job period (that's meant just to clarify the semantics, not as a real guess about the cause).  WRT your last question I've heard a large mug of coffee works...

Comment: A large mug of coffee with something in it?  I will try again tomorrow when her coffee might not taste like almonds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that the protocol was ipps rather than ipp

How it got that way is a mystery; the solution was to simply re install the printer through the CUPS find printers menu.  No wife required.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as a unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

**Symptoms**
On my printer (Xerox) I had installed via CUPS on linux (Fedora) that was working smoothly all the time until I interrupted a job being printed.

Since that time I was not able to print anything on that printer - all I got was that mysterious message `Unable to add document to print job`.

Finally I found out that it was caused by printer `Error Policy` that was set to `Stop printer` and this leads to printer state `Paused`.

**See the status of the printer**
In the list of printers http://localhost:631/printers/ is column Status with `Paused - "Paused"`.

Using `lpstat` command

```
$ lpstat -p printer-name
printer printer-name disabled since ... - Paused
```

**Enable the printer**

So simple, run `cupsenable` command with printer name as the only parameter:

```
$ cupsenable printer-name
```

And review the status:

```
$ lpstat -p printer-name
printer Xprinter-name is idle.  enabled since ...
```

And the printer accepts new jobs again..

**Root cause**

Finally I found out in the printer `Error Policy` set to `Stop printer` that changed the status to paused. So I changed the error policy to `Abort job`

Hope this help.